# in-place import in other version control systems? dvcs?

Tags: svn, version-control, import

I use subversion's in-place import [(read for details)](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#in-place-import) for configuration file version control in /etc and my home directory.  It works well for me, but I've been seeing alot better/faster version control systems cropping up and want to convert.  I tried mercurial, and it doesn't really support this feature of checking out a working copy of a single subfolder in a repository- it seems to want you to check out the whole thing at once.

Do other version control systems allow this?  I've only tried cvs, mercurial, and subversion.  Examples welcome.

Comment: Which one of cvs and mercurial was alot better/faster than subversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [git](http://git-scm.com/) (assuming it is installed already):

```
cd /etc
git init-db
chmod og-rwx .git
git add .
git commit -a -m"initial import"
```

More elaborated version with automatic update when apt is used:

[Maintain /etc with git](http://www.jukie.net/~bart/blog/20070312134706)

---

For [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/) (assuming it is installed already):

```
cd /etc
hg init
chmod og-rwx .hg
hg add
hg ci -m "initial checkin"
```

More elaborated version with automatic update when apt is used:

[Maintain /etc with mercurial](http://michael-prokop.at/blog/2007/03/14/maintain-etc-with-mercurial-on-debian/)

Comment: I see that those both make a new repository out of /etc is there an alternative method that would allow me to add /etc as a subfolder to an already-existing repository?  Or in turn, check out/clone only that subfolder?

Comment: There is no real way for partial or sparse checkouts for git (although under development I think) but in git there is no real overhead to have multiple repositories. For Mercurial I'm not sure. But you can google yourself using "mercurial partial checkout" or/and "mercurial sparse checkout" as keywords